# Wrong answer in "Discrepancies in voter list"(VOTERS) on CodeChef

Tags: c, arrays

I am solving this problem on Codechef. But I am getting a wrong answer for the code that I am submitting.
Problem Link::  http://www.codechef.com/problems/VOTERS/

Brief Problem Description:: There are 3 officials who collect the data for voters in the area, but there are a few discrepancies in the data they collect, and the final list prepared includes only those voters which occur twice or more times in the list prepared by the 3 officials. We have to find the final number of voters and print their voter ids.

My code::

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[150000],b[50000],c[100000][2];
int merge(int p,int q);
int main()
{
    int n1,n2,n3;
    int i,j,k,count,val;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&n1,&n2,&n3);
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);

    k=merge(n1,n2);

    count=0;
    j=0;
    for(i=0;i<n3;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&val);
        while(val>c[j][0] && j<k)
        {
            if(c[j][1]==2)
            {
                a[count]=c[j][0];
                count++;
            }
            j++;
        }

        if(val==c[j][0] && j<k)
        {
            a[count]=c[j][0];
            count++;j++;
        }
    }    
    for(i=j;i<k;i++)
    {
        if(c[i][1]==2)
        {
            a[count]=c[j][0];
            count++;
        }  
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);

    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);

    return 0;
}


int merge(int p,int q)
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    while(i<p && j<q)
    {
        if(a[i]<b[j])
        {
            c[k][0]=a[i];
            c[k][1]=1;
            i++;k++;
        }
        else if(a[i]>b[j])
        {
            c[k][0]=b[j];
            c[k][1]=1;
            k++;j++;
        } 
        else
        {
            c[k][0]=a[i];
            c[k][1]=2;
            i++;j++;k++;
        }
    }
    while(i<p)
    { 
        c[k][0]=a[i];
        c[k][1]=1;
        i++;k++;
    }
    while(j<q)
    {
        c[k][0]=b[j];
        c[k][1]=1;
        j++;k++;
    }
    return k;
}
```

A brief description of my algorithm::

I have take 3 arrays `a[]`,`b[]` and `c[][]`. First I enter the voter ids given by the first worker in array `a[]`. Then I enter the voter ids collected by worker 2 in the array `b[]`. Then I merge the data collected by these two workers into the array `c[][]` in ascending order and use the second row of `c[][]` for storing how many times an id value has occurred in the the 2 arrays (1 or 2).
Then, for the the third worker, I take the id values as input 1 by 1 in a single variable `val`. Then I find its correct position in the merged array `c[][]`, and see if that element occurs in `c[][]`. If it does then I include it in my final ans array, else I ignore. (Since if an element doesn't exist in the merged array that means that it is occurring for the first time, hence we shall neglect it).
Side by side I also check if for any element in `c[][]` has occurred twice (i.e., if `c[i][1]=2`), and also include that in the answer.
After this I check if I have any left over elements in the merged array and have occurred twice and also include them in the final answer.

I hope I could make it clear what I intend to do. I know its very complicated (the way I explained) but please help guys.

I have tried a lot of test cases I don't why this code gives a wrong answer. :(
Please help guys. Thanks for any help in advance.. :)

Comment: Note that merging only works if lists `a` and `b` are already sorted. Also, in `main` it looks like you'll add the small voter ID numbers to the output list multiple times (you can confirm this using small test cases, and adding `printf`s to your code). Finally, if the voter IDs are known to be small integers (e.g. less than 10,000,000) then there is a much easier way to solve this problem (using a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Mathematical_definition)).

Comment: @user3386109 Lists `a` and `b` are given as sorted in the question. Further, I wanted to use histogram sir, but the question just says integer values in the list, it doesn't specify any range, so I am not sure what size array to use. And, how I am I putting small voter ids many times? Couldn't understand sir..

Comment: @user3386109 this is my ideone link for code:: [link](http://ideone.com/oL44RT)  in my `for` loop from line 20-38. I scan every element in the third list, and if the element is greater than element that is pointed by `j`, then I increment `j` till its correct position, and then if its equal then I put it in the final answer, but if it is less then I simply do nothing.

Comment: If I'm right, first `while` loop after the `scanf("%d",&val);` has a problem. Put a `printf("adding %d\n",c[j][0]);` inside the `if` statement to confirm.

Comment: @user3386109 sir, i tried doing it, but couldn't figure out any test case which adds any extra lesser numbers into the output.. :(

Comment: Sorry, I tried a few test cases, and I was wrong about the loop. The only test case that I found that had a problem was `4 2 5  15 16 16 17   44 45   15 16 16 44 45`, but I'm not sure if that's allowed by the rules or not.

Comment: @user3386109 No that isn't sir, you cannot have 2 same numbers in 1 list. Anyways I found the error. :D In the for loop just before `printf("%d\n",count);` in the `if` condition I compare `c[i][1]` but I copy `c[j][0]` which should have been `c[i][0]`.  I feel like hitting my head in the wall.. haha.. Thank you so much for trying to help. You rock sirr.. :)

Comment: Don't add "SOLVED" to the question title. The way to indicate that your problem has been solved is to accept an answer. You can post and accept an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's and error in for loop::

```
    for(i=j;i<k;i++)
    {
        if(c[i][1]==2)
        {
            a[count]=c[j][0];
            count++;
        }  
    }
```

where the loop runs on i, but in the `if` condition i perform `a[count]=c[j][0]`, which was a very minor bug, but made me think for hours. Thanks to everyone for looking into the question. And extremely sorry for bothering you all with such a lame problem. Thank you.. :)